# Why is apps script giving me this error while I'm trying to connect to my realtime firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

I am needing help to connect the content of an automactically updated spreadsheet (with columns of id, date etc, note that the column of Id that will be automatically updated too, but atm its manually added as 1, 2 - 29) to realtime database on Firebase. It's my first time using it too! However when using the code that I had looked up and edited, it gave me server errors, for these two parts: writeDataToFirebase and initialize at code.gs 49 and 44 respectively. (It must be an issue with coding as its not the internet). Would love some help!

And Oh ive copied the appscript.json file too, from this website https://medium.com/firebase-developers/sheets-to-firebase-33132e31935b , and used a script id too for a firebaseApp (I cant seem to find a custom way and had taken from a previous example), I may not understand it fully, so any help will be extremely helpful!! Thank you!

This is the code I've done

```js
/**
* Copyright 2019 Google LLC.
* SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/

function getEnvironment() {
 var environment = {
   spreadsheetID: "-",
   firebaseUrl: "-"
 };
 return environment;
}

// Creates a Google Sheets on change trigger for the specific sheet
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(spreadsheetID) {
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 var triggerExists = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   if (triggers[i].getTriggerSourceId() == spreadsheetID) {
     triggerExists = true;
     break;
   }
 }

 if (!triggerExists) {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
   ScriptApp.newTrigger("importSheet")
     .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
     .onChange()
     .create();
 }
}

// Delete all the existing triggers for the project
function deleteTriggers() {
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
 }
}

// Initialize
function initialize(e) {
 writeDataToFirebase(getEnvironment().spreadsheetID);
}

// Write the data to the Firebase URL
function writeDataToFirebase(spreadsheetID) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetID);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
 createSpreadsheetEditTrigger(spreadsheetID);
 var sheets = ss.getSheets();
 for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   importSheet(sheets[i]);
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[i]);
 }
}

// A utility function to generate nested object when
// given a keys in array format
function assign(obj, keyPath, value) {
 lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length - 1;
 for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++i) {
   key = keyPath[i];
   if (!(key in obj)) obj[key] = {};
   obj = obj[key];
 }
 obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
}

// Import each sheet when there is a change
function importSheet() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var name = sheet.getName();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 var dataToImport = {};

 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
   dataToImport[data[i][0]] = {};
   for (var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
     assign(dataToImport[data[i][0]], data[0][j].split("__"), data[i][j]);
   }
 }

 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

 var firebaseUrl =
   getEnvironment().firebaseUrl + sheet.getParent().getId() + "/" + name;
 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByURL(firebaseUrl, token);
 base.setData("", dataToImport);
}
```